# The on() function with jQuery using mouseover does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to create a small popup box when I hover my text. But it doesn't work and I do not understand why... Could you help me?  I want to show up the "data-popup" content when I hover "surpi". This line of html is generated dynamicaly by javascript. Here is my code :

```
<a href="#" data-popup="surpris">supri</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  popup();
});

function popup() {
  $("#correction").on("mouseover", "a", function() {
    var data = $(this).attr("data-popup"),
      offsetDataTop = $(this).offset().top,
      offsetDataLeft = $(this).offset().left;

    if (data != "") {
      // .popup creation
      $("body").prepend("<div class='popup'>" + data + "</div>");
      // .popup properties
      var popupWidth = $(".popup").innerWidth(),
        thisWith = $(this).innerWidth(),
        marginLeft = (thisWith - popupWidth) / 2;
      // .popup init
      $(".popup").css({
        opacity: 0,
        top: offsetDataTop - 40,
        left: offsetDataLeft + marginLeft
      });
      // .popup animation
      $(".popup").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        marginTop: 20
      }, "fast");
    }
  }, function() {
    $(".popup").remove();
  }); // .popup removed
};
```

Comment: You want mouseenter and mouseleave for the on event

Comment: Can you be more specific? thanks

Comment: Or rather, "I would use mouseenter and mouseleave for this event", example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do this using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#correction').on('mouseenter', '[data-popup]', function() {
    var $this=$(this)
    var data =$this.attr("data-popup").trim();
    var offsetDataTop = $this.offset().top;
    var offsetDataLeft = $this.offset().left;
    if (data != "") {
      // .popup creation
      var $popup=$("<div class='popup'>" + data + "</div>");
      $("body").prepend($popup);
      // .popup properties
      var marginLeft = ($this.innerWidth() - $popup.innerWidth()) / 2;
      // .popup init
      $popup.css({
        opacity: 0,
        top: offsetDataTop - 40,
        left: offsetDataLeft + marginLeft
      }).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        marginTop: 20
      }, "fast");
    }
  }).on('mouseleave', '[data-popup]', function() {
      $(".popup").remove();
  })
});
```

```css
.popup{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="correction">
<br>
<br>
  <a href="#" data-popup="surpris">supri</a>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

`$("#correction").on("mouseover", "a", function() {`

By this:

`$("#correction").on("mouseenter", "a", function() {`

Answer (score -1):

1) You're targeting #correction but that doesn't exist in your example. You need to add this id to the element

```
<a href="#" id="correction" data-popup="surpris">supri</a>
```

2) You don't need to execute the popup method the way you have it in your code, you can bind directly to the element by:

```
$("#correction").on("mouseover", function() {
    // Do stuff
});
```

3) You need to remove the popup element using the mouseleave event. You can do this in the same method like so:

```
$("#correction").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        // Do stuff
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        // Do stuff
    }
})
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/mark_c/jtwnyeLy/ for a quick example.